# How To Get A Count Of CSV Log Entries Per Day

Tags: clojure

If I had a CSV file that was something like the following:

```
date,description,
Mon Jul 25 14:34:49 EDT 2016, some entry,
Mon Jul 25 17:35:11 EDT 2016, some other entry,
Mon Jul 25 21:52:05 EDT 2016, yet another entry,
Mon Jul 25 22:35:59 EDT 2016, some entry,
Mon Jul 25 23:54:19 EDT 2016, some other entry,
Tue Jul 26 00:31:41 EDT 2016, some entry,
Wed Jul 27 15:45:08 EDT 2016, yet another entry,
Wed Jul 27 16:15:50 EDT 2016, some entry,
```

What would be a good approach to get a data structure that was a count of entries per day, so that I would get:

[{:date "2016-07-25" :count 5}...]

I am reading a csv file and returning the day counts as JSON using clojure.data.json/write-str, so the above data structure may be better in another format.

Comment: Please add what you have have tried and how it failed. A naive start would be to parse the date, only you yyy-mm-dd and then use `frequencies` or maybe `group-by` if you need more than just the count.

Comment: I realize I should have done more before asking. I'll try a naive start and report back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this. I added comments at each step of the pipeline:

```clj
(def lines "date,description,
Mon Jul 25 14:34:49 EDT 2016, some entry,
Mon Jul 25 17:35:11 EDT 2016, some other entry,
Mon Jul 25 21:52:05 EDT 2016, yet another entry,
Mon Jul 25 22:35:59 EDT 2016, some entry,
Mon Jul 25 23:54:19 EDT 2016, some other entry,
Tue Jul 26 00:31:41 EDT 2016, some entry,
Wed Jul 27 15:45:08 EDT 2016, yet another entry,
Wed Jul 27 16:15:50 EDT 2016, some entry,")

(->> ; get the lines
     lines  
     ; split them                                             
     clojure.string/split-lines   
     ; discard header                              
     rest            
     ; keep only the date                                           
     (map #(first (clojure.string/split % #",")))     
     ; make them Date instances          
     (map #(Date. %))          
     ; group them by yyyy-MM-dd                                
     (group-by #(.format (SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy-MM-dd") %))  
     ; make a map whose keys are {:date :count}  
     (reduce-kv #(assoc %1 %2 {:date %2 :count (count %3)}) {}) 
     ; keep only the values of this built map
     vals)                      

=> ({:date "2016-07-25", :count 2} {:date "2016-07-26", :count 4} {:date "2016-07-27", :count 2})
```

Another way using `frequencies` instead of `group-by`:

```clj
(->> ; get the lines
     lines 
     ; split them
     clojure.string/split-lines rest
     ; keep the date
     (map #(first (clojure.string/split % #",")))
     ; format them as yyyy-MM-dd
     (map #(.format (SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy-MM-dd") (Date. %)))
     ; compute the frequencies
     frequencies
     ; build a map out of it, this time you don't need to count yourself since frequencies did it for you
     (reduce-kv #(assoc %1 %2 {:date %2 :count %3}) {})
     ; keep only the values of the map we built
     vals)

=> ({:date "2016-07-25", :count 2} {:date "2016-07-26", :count 4} {:date "2016-07-27", :count 2})
```

Performance-wise they are similar, on my computer it takes around 2 seconds for both to analyze 100k rows.

If performance is a problem the bottleneck you may want to create only one `SimpleDateFormat` or even format yourself the date from string to `yyyy-MM-dd` without creating a `Date` at all. But only if needed, performance is already pretty decent :)

Comment: This is elegant! I did come up with a solution that is so convoluted I don't dare post it. It is awesome to see your solution after my terrible one. I'm glad I had to go through the exercise before seeing what you came up with. I'll go with your solution, for sure. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @THX1137, I updated the answer with `frequencies` to show the difference and also some perf related comments. Keep up with Clojure, there's no shame to have, you'll soon be able to do better than this ;)